# Linux terminal text editor which behaves like GUI ones

Tags: linux, text-editor

I'm looking for a linux text editor to run in a terminal on a remote computer over SSH, for coding (mainly in Ruby), but I'm familiar with graphical text editors (like Kate, Geany, GEdit, etc.), and I would like to work on it using similar keybindings.

In particular, I want to select blocks with SHIFT+ARROWS and indent/unindent them with TAB/SHIFT+TAB, and undo with CTRL+Z, etc, like EDIT for DOS.

I've tried vi, vim, jed, joe, nano and mcedit.

Mcedit is the nearest choice, since we can use SHIFT+ARROWS to highlight a block, but it doesn't indent blocks with TAB, and the SHIFT+ARROWS didn't work over SSH (maybe a local misconfiguration?).

What do you suggest?

(I prefer terminal text editors in this question, since I could use them everywhere, but if you are going to suggest a local editor with SSH/SFTP feature, keep in mind that I'm intending to use it on an Android device.)

Comment: Can't resist: I'm using 'vim' in the terminal, and have the totally same keybindings in the my graphical one, called `gvim`. ;)

Comment: There is 'slap' too , resembling with sublime text I guess , but you'll have to install nodejs first.

Comment: These days I'm playing with [ruco](https://github.com/grosser/ruco), but I got stuck with utf-8 issues. If I resolve that, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: **[nefte](https://sourceforge.net/projects/efte/)**,  (the console version of **efte**, which is an improved revision of **fte**, which is a menu-driven 90s era _Borland_ editor work-alike), doesn't quite fit the OP specs: it has shift arrow select and Ctrl+z undo, but indent is 'Alt-i'.

Comment: I think vim-gnome is something you should check out. If I were you I would also check out emacs the gui version.

Answer (score 1):

This is posted long time ago but, just in case someone need it, there is ***[Micro](https://micro-editor.github.io/)***

Keybings are very similar to ones found in in most GUI like Kate, Sublime Text etc...

Example, you can use Ctrl+Z to *undo*, Ctrl+C to *copy*, Ctrl+X to *cut* etc...

Answer (score 1):

[Textadept](https://foicica.com/textadept/) is my text editor of choice. I've used it happily on Linux, OSX, and Windows for years. From the homepage for OP's interests:

> - Textadept runs on Windows, Mac OSX, Linux, and BSD. It also has a **terminal version**, which is ideal for work on remote machines.
> - It comes with built-in light, dark, and **terminal themes**.
> - Textadept is entirely **keyboard driven**. The editor defines key bindings for nearly every action. You can easily reassign existing bindings or create new ones.

A couple tiny screen shots:

[image: ncurses version]

[image: terminal theme]

In addition, it is actively developed and the developer is very responsive. Highly recommended.