# Linux console text editor with Windows/Mac style shift-arrow text selection, cut, quit and save

Tags: linux, text-editor, unix

I have a terminal novice user-base who need to do some extremely light text editing from a console (authoring [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) commits, etc.). I'd like to set EDITOR to something that keyboard binding-wise feels as much as possible like a standard "web browser text area" with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to save/quit.

I've tried [jed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JED_(text_editor)), ne, [JOE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe%27s_Own_Editor), [nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano) and [micro](https://micro-editor.github.io/), but none of them have all the features I'd like:

1. Block selection: Shift-Arrow should expand the cursor in the appropriate direction to select a block, just like on Windows, Mac, [GNOME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME), etc.
2. Copy, Cut, andPaste: Should be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>
3. Save: Should be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
4. Quit: Should be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>
5. Nice to have: an [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) menubar (ala ne) that pop up when they press <kbd>Esc</kbd>
6. Nice to have: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to find, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to find next

Any suggestions?

Comment: Apart from the required *learn Vi* joke, try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/235664/how-can-i-change-the-keyboard-shortcuts-in-nano

Comment: Related: *[Linux terminal text editor which behaves like GUI ones](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10068)*

Comment: On *[Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour)* today: *[Which terminal text editor uses GUI-like keyboard shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352380)*

Answer (score 1):

You can customize key bindings for nano in /etc/nanorc

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/nanorc.5.html

Answer (score 1):

`mcedit`, which ships with Midnight-Commander (`mc`), a terminal orthodox file-manager. You will need to remap the keys in the file `mc.keymap`, though. For example, the defauls for copy, paste and cut are:

```
Store = ctrl-insert
Paste = shift-insert
Cut = shift-delete
```

Change them to

```
Store = ctrl-c
Paste = ctrl-v
Cut = ctrl-x
```

Also be sure to turn off `Persistent selection` in the editor `Options > General` menu. This makes selected text be replaced by what you type (if you type something).